# Does the incompressible Navier-Stokes equation have a smooth solution if the initial vorticity is smooth and $p$ integrable for any $p$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, regularity, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

Consider the incompressible Navier-Stokes equation on $(0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^3$ for fixed $T>0$.
If the sequence of mollified initial vorticities $(\omega_0^{\nu})_{\nu}$ is uniformly bounded in $L^1\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, has uniform compact support (that is $\text{supp}(\omega_0^{\nu})=B_R(0)$ for some $R>0$ and all $\nu>0$) and is smooth one can decompose the Biot-Savart kernel to observe that the initial velocities are in fact smooth and uniformly bounded in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$ as
$$\|u_0^{\nu}\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq \|K\cdot\mathbb{1}_{B_1(0)}\|_{L^{\frac{3}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^3)}\|\omega_0^{\nu}\|_{L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)}+\leq \|K\cdot\mathbb{1}_{B_1(0)^C}\|_{L^{{3}}(\mathbb{R}^3)}\|\omega_0^{\nu}\|_{L^{\frac{4}{3}}(\mathbb{R}^3)}.$$
The theory of Calderon-Zygmund ensures that $(\nabla u_0^{\nu})_{\nu}$ is bounded in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and hence $(u_0^{\nu})_{\nu}$ is bounded in $W^{1,p}$ for any $p\in [1,\infty]$.
Questions:

- According to [Robinson, Chapter 7.1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/threedimensional-navierstokes-equations/82EDFE5B6F236CE381E7D80E947BC94A) one would need $u_0^{\nu}\in W^{2,m}$ for some $m\geq 2$ in order to get a strong solution which can be shown to be smooth by bootstrapping. Can I somehow proceed to use [Robinson](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/threedimensional-navierstokes-equations/82EDFE5B6F236CE381E7D80E947BC94A) ?
- Is it maybe easier to show that the Navier-Stokes equation has a smooth solution $(0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^3$ if the initial condition is smooth/ initial vorticity is smooth and fulfils the integrability conditions from above?
- This made me wonder about the Navier-Stokes millenium problem: Due to https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/navierstokes.pdf to solve the millenium problem they demand the derivatives of the initial condition to fulfil some growth condition which seems to be stronger than what Robinson assumed on the initial condition in [Robinson](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/threedimensional-navierstokes-equations/82EDFE5B6F236CE381E7D80E947BC94A) . Is there an easy way to see why one cannot get the result with the conditions [Robinson](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/threedimensional-navierstokes-equations/82EDFE5B6F236CE381E7D80E947BC94A)  gave?